# migrating change from Development to to production environment

Tags: database, liquibase, ddl

All,

I trying to implement Liquibase for database DDL related code promotion from one to another environment. 
Let's for the first time when i am doing deployment generateChangeLog will generate full db DDL which can be executed in another environment.
Now i have added new table and altered some column in development. How to generate changeset for just these two changes.

Regards,
Anupam

Comment: You shouldn't add or alter tables manually. You should write the corresponding Liquibase changeSets and run **those**

Comment: So there is no way to generate the delta changes?

Comment: That's not how this is intended. If you start doing "delta diffs" between you environments you are missing the idea behind tools like that. The idea is to explicitly **write** your migrations as Liquibase changeset, store them in your version control and apply them in a controlled manner. Manually changing the database will always get you in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As was already told by @a_horse_with_no_name

> You shouldn't add or alter tables manually. You should write the corresponding Liquibase changeSets and run **those**

Perhaps liquibase [diff](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) or [diffChangeLog](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diffChangeLog.html) will help you, but using these commands in such a way indeed goes against the idea behind Liquibase.